# unable to locate package Arpspoof

Tags: kali-linux, arp-spoofing

Can not find the tool arpspoof by using the `apt-get install` on Kali.
After checking by typing `apt-cache search` there is no result either.

Does this mean the tool is not available anymore? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that arpspoof is a tool from the **[dsniff](https://su2.info/doc/arpspoof.php)** package. As long as you install it, then the arpspoof is ready to be used.

> The tool used here is called arpspoof and is distributed in the dsniff
>   package.